# How can I prevent interactive-rebase from running verification hooks on commits?

Tags: git, interactive

I have a range of commits that fail the tests that are committed with them. I need to interactive-rebase across these commits; but the hooks are failing, and causing each commit to screw up, forcing me to manually `git commit -n` each step.

Is there a way to automate this? `git rebase --interactive --no-verify` doesn't do what I'd expect.

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon the same problem, but the only answer I found required modifying the hook itself.

[Here](https://gmurphey.github.io/2013/02/02/ignoring-git-hooks-when-rebasing.html#.W7INAy3ngUE) the author suggests filtering this situation using the branch name:

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //') 

if [[ $BRANCH_NAME != *"no branch"* ]]
then
  # your regularly scheduled hook
fi
```

I changed the condition a little bit, as my git output looks like `(no branch, rebasing some-branch-name)`.
It does not solve my specific case, but maybe someone will find this question and use this approach in future.

Comment: that's pretty neat! perhaps `REBASING=$(git branch | grep '\* (no branch')` would be already enough for checking on the if statement as `if [ -z "$REBASING" ] ...`

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution from https://blog.swwomm.com/2018/06/skip-pre-commit-hook-on-git-rebase-or.html:

Add this to the pre-commit hook script:

```bash
if [ "$NO_VERIFY" ]; then
    echo 'pre-commit hook skipped' 1>&2
    exit 0
fi
```

and then update `NO_VERIFY` when running the interactive rebase:

```bash
NO_VERIFY=1 git rebase -i master # or `git merge some-branch` or whatever
```

Comment: Or more simply `NO_VERIFY=1  git rebase -i master` (in one line) so that the variable is not required to be emptied afterwards.

Comment: Would it be possible to detect  `--no-verify` parameter instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another very quick and non-invasive workaround which doesn't require modifying your existing hooks:

```
git config core.hooksPath .no-hooks
```

Once you're done, don't forget to restore the hooks.  If you're using the global default hooks path of `$GIT_DIR/hooks` then you can just revert this override:

```
git config --unset core.hooksPath
```

or if you're using something like [husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/) then you'll need:

```
git config core.hooksPath .husky
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Variation on the [answer given by @s6mike](https://superuser.com/a/1732309/167207):

Observed that there are already some GIT env vars in the hook context so for my case when wanting to avoid hooks explicitly for rewording a commit without having to set a new env var

```
if [[ "${GIT_REFLOG_ACTION}" =~ "rebase".*"reword" ]]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: @Qwerty inside the relevant (pre-commit) hook, before running the actual check.
But note that I stated that this is for the reword case.  That is if I'm only editing commit message please don't waste my time re-linting/testing code